# How to add items(object) to the combobox in javasscript

Tags: c#, ajax, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

My Code:

```
 function onLoad(e)
    {
         var element = document.getElementById('cmbGender');
         $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                    url: "@(Url.Action("LoadGenderNames", "Search"))",
                    success: function (data) {
                         // How to add the "data" object items in to the combo box here. 
                    },
                });
    }
```

How to add items(object) to the combobox inside the function(data). Thanks.

**EDIT**: 
It is the Telerik combobox Html.Telerik().ComboBox() .Name("cmbGender")

Comment: What is your combo box? Is it a JQuery UI widget?Or a HTML5 input with list attribute?

Comment: It is the Telerik combobox Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
                        .Name("cmbGender")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind combobox by ajax you can use next code:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ComboBox().Name("cmbGender") 
            .AutoFill(true)
            .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax()
                                           .Select("LoadGenderNames", "Search"))                
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data is an array of strings, you can do the following:

```
success: function (data)
{
    element.trackChanges();

    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
        comboItem.set_text(data[i]);
        element.get_items().add(comboItem);
    }

    element.commitChanges();
},
```

You can find more information on [Telerik website](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-items-client-side-code.html).

Comment: Your answer to RadCombobox, but author says about asp.net mvc extensions from telerik

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'trackChanges'. Thanks

Comment: As @KirillBestemyanov spotted, my code is for `Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox` and not for the Telerik MVC extension... You should try his proposition.